# BigDecimal in scala

Tags: java, scala, math

I've stumbled across interisting thing(maybe only for me) in scala. In a word, if we have a BigDecimal(let say `val a = BigDecimal(someValue)` where `someValue` is decimal string) the result of operation

```
N * a / N == a
```

will not always produce `true`. I suppose that it relates to any opeartions on BigDecimals. I know that in scala BigDecimals are created with default MathContext set to `DECIMAL128`(with `HALF_EVEN` rounding and precision equals to 34). I've discovered such behavior on decimals with more than 30 digits after point

My questions is why I get such results. Can I somehow control them?

**example**

`-0.007633587786259541984732824427480916`

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Would using rational numbers help?

Comment: Like @0__ said, you need to use rational numbers if you want exact precision. If you use inexact precision you'll always encounter rounding errors in some cases. [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) provides support for rational number math in Scala.

Comment: The default mathContext with precision=34 is used when instantiating BigDecimal. As I understand that mean that for 34 digits after point the result must be the same, not matter what the operation was used to get the BigDecimal(some kind of guaranteed precision). Also when comparing 2 bigdecimals only 34 digits must be taken into account. So if the decimals differ onlly in digits after 34 position, the they must be equal. Am I right?

Comment: Not really. Let's simplify from 34 to 2. Precision of 2 means the BigDecimal stores 2 significant figures and throws the rest away. If you do BigDecimal("989", PrecisionOf2), you will get 9.9E+2 (or 990) because it rounded to 2 sig figs. Also it does depend on the operation: addition, subtraction, multiplication can yield exact results while division doesn't always. The first example in my answer shows why the digits will not be the same during comparison. 1 / 3 = 0.333... Since BigDecimal will only store 34 digits, there will be 34 3's. 0.3333333333333333333333333333333333 * 3 != 1.

Comment: To give another example: if you use RoundingMode.UP for the division of 1 / 3 you'll get 0.3333333333333333333333333333333334. When you multiply that by 3 again using RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN, you'll get 1. This is because 0.3333333333333333333333333333333334 * 3 = 1.0000000000000000000000000000000002 which is 35 sig figs, so it has to round that result back to 34 sig figs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As previous comments already point out, this is not avoidable with irrational numbers. This is because there's no way to represent an irrational number using the standard numeric types (if at all). Since I have no examples with irrational numbers (even PI is limited to a fixed number of digits, and therefore can be expressed as a quotient of 2 whole numbers, making it rational), I will use repeating decimals to illustrate the problem. I changed `N*a/N` to `a/N*N` because it demonstrates the problem better with whole numbers, but they're equivalent:

```
a = BigDecimal(1)
N = BigDecimal(3)
a/N = 0.333...
a/N*N = 0.999...
```

As you can see in the example above, you can use as many decimal places and any rounding mode, but the result is never going to be equal to 1. (Though it IS possible to get 1 using a different rounding mode per operation, i.e. `BigDecimal(3, roundHalfEven) * (BigDecimal(1, roundUp) / 3)`)

One thing you can do to control the number comparison is to use a higher precision when performing your arithmetic operations and round to the desired (lower) precision when comparing:

```
val HighPrecision = new java.math.MathContext(36, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
val TargetPrecision = java.math.MathContext.DECIMAL128;

val a = BigDecimal(1, HighPrecision)
val N = BigDecimal(3, HighPrecision)
(a/N*N).round(TargetPrecision) == a.round(TargetPrecision)
```

In the example above, the last expression evaluates to `true`.

**UPDATE**

To answer your comment, although BigDecimal is arbitrary precision, it is still limited by a precision. It can be 34 or it can be 1000000 (if you have enough memory). BigDecimal does NOT know that `1 / 3` is `0.33<repeating>`. If you think about how division works, there's no way for BigDecimal to conclusively know that it's repeating without performing the division to infinite decimal places. But since a precision of 2 indicates it can stop dividing after 2 decimal places, it only knows that `1 / 3` is `0.33`.

Comment: see my last comment to my post